Preprocess image for better barcode read results
I am trying to read barcodes from images. Unfortunately, sometimes images are of low quality. I tried to preprocess the image so that the Pyzbar library would return better results.
I try with
resizing
def resize(_image, _scalar):
    x, y = _image.size
    return _image.resize((int(round(x*_scalar)), int(round(y*_scalar))))

blurring/sharpening
from PIL import ImageEnhance
def blur(_image, _sharpness):
    return ImageEnhance.Sharpness(_image).enhance(_sharpness)

Binarisation
def binarisation(_image, factor=127):
    _img = np.array(_image)
    _img = grey(_img)
    ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(_img,factor,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    return th1

Gaussian binarisation
def gaussian_binar(_image, t1=11, t2=2):
    _img = np.array(_image)
    gray_image = grey(_img)
    return cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,t1,t2)

Otsu binarisation
def otsu(_image, win_size=5):
    _img = np.array(_image)
    gray_image = grey(_img)
    _blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_image,(win_size,win_size),0)
    ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(_blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    return th3

Clahe
from PIL import ImageOps
def normalise_CLAHE(_image):
    _img = np.array(_image)
    cvim = grey(_img)
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE()
    clahe_im = clahe.apply(cvim)
    return clahe_im

with erosion and dilatation
def erode(_image, _iteration=1, _size=3):
    _img = np.array(_image)
    _img = grey(_img)
    _kernel = np.ones((_size, _size), np.uint8)
    return cv2.erode(_img, _kernel, iterations=_iteration)

def dilate(_image, _iteration=1, _size=3):
    _img = np.array(_image)
    _img = grey(_img)
    _kernel = np.ones((_size, _size), np.uint8)
    return cv2.dilate(_img, _kernel, iterations=_iteration)

and of course with the combination of those
import os

class ContinueI(Exception):
    pass
continue_i = ContinueI()

strategies = {}
images_solved = {}

directory = 'test_images'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    try:
        file_name=os.path.join(directory, filename)
        print(f'___________*** {file_name} ***___________')

        image = Image.open(file_name)
        find = search_for_codes(image, 'Original', file_name)
        if find:
            raise continue_i

        img = image.copy()
        for scalar in [0.5, 1, 2]:
            img1 = resize(img, scalar)
            find = search_for_codes(img1, f'Scaled {scalar}', file_name)
            if find:
                raise continue_i

            for sharpness in [1, 0.1, 0.5, 1.5, 2]:
                img2 = blur(img1, sharpness)
                find = search_for_codes(img2, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}', file_name)
                if find:
                    raise continue_i

                for bin in [50, 150]:
                    img3 = binarization(img2, bin)
                    find = search_for_codes(img3, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}, bin {bin}', file_name)
                    if find:
                        raise continue_i

                    # for mor in [3,7,15,21]:
                    #     img36 = morpholog(img3, mor)
                    #     search_for_codes(img36, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}, bin {bin}, mor {mor}')

                    for er in [1,3,5]:
                        img37 = erode(img3, 1, er)
                        find = search_for_codes(img37, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}, bin {bin}, er {er}', file_name)
                        if find:
                            raise continue_i

                    for dil in [1,3,5]:
                        img38 = dilate(img3, 1, dil)
                        find = search_for_codes(img38, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}, bin {bin}, dil {dil}', file_name)
                        if find:
                            raise continue_i

                    for er_dil in [1,3,5]:
                        img39 = dilate(img3, 1, er_dil)
                        img39 = erode(img39, 1, er_dil)
                        find = search_for_codes(img39, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}, bin {bin}, dil {er_dil} + er {er_dil}', file_name)
                        if find:
                            raise continue_i

                for gau in [3, 5, 7, 11,13, 15, 17]:
                    img4 = gausian_binar(img2, gau, 2)
                    search_for_codes(img4, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}, gau {gau}')

                for ots in [3, 5]:
                    img5 = otsu(img2, ots)
                    find = search_for_codes(img5, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}, ots {ots}', file_name)
                    if find:
                        raise continue_i

                for mor in [3,7,15,21]:
                    img6 = morpholog(img2, mor)
                    find = search_for_codes(img6, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}, mor {mor}', file_name)
                    if find:
                        raise continue_i

                for er in [1,3,5]:
                    img7 = erode(img2, 1, er)
                    find = search_for_codes(img7, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}, er {er}', file_name)
                    if find:
                        raise continue_i

                for dil in [1,3,5]:
                    img8 = dilate(img2, 1, dil)
                    find = search_for_codes(img8, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}, dil {dil}', file_name)
                    if find:
                        raise continue_i

                for er_dil in [1,3,5]:
                    img9 = dilate(img2, 1, er_dil)
                    img9 = erode(img9, 1, er_dil)
                    find = search_for_codes(img9, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}, dil {er_dil} + er {er_dil}', file_name)
                    if find:
                        raise continue_i

                img7 = normalise_CLAHE(img2)
                find = search_for_codes(img7, f'Scaled {scalar}, blured {sharpness}, clahe', file_name)
                if find:
                    raise continue_i

    except ContinueI:
        continue

print(strategies)

But for some images, even if it looked ok to me (looking with my eyes), the library could not read it, no matter what I did.
An example is this image:

(the white rectangle is for privacy reasons - only here at StackOverflow)
Can anyone suggest something else to do with those images? Any other approach for preprocessing images?

Have you tried thresholding on black, then inverting, using cv2.inRange()?

I didn’t, but if I understand correctly this is similar to binarisation? I will try.

Yes, similar, but may be more discriminating. You process directly on the colored input rather than converting to gray first, then simple threshold.

You can also try division normalization followed by thresholding.  Division normalization is dividing the image by a blurred version. You can try either a small Gaussian blur (say sigma=3) or a large one (say sigma=33). If the latter, I likely will not need thresholding. Search this forum. I have posted a number of answers using that.

I have to ask: what's with all those underscores?

zbar is supposed to handle images straight from cameras, right? without any pre-processing, right? if it doesn't, submit a bug to them. -- before trying random operations and hoping that they do anything, you should determine why zbar fails to find and read the barcode. "why" in the white-box technical sense, not in the "bad input" sense. -- question requires a [mre]. I don't even see imports.
